# How do I create an iterator that will return only the elements that are different in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, stack

More details of the issue:I need to create an iterator for a Stack of Strings that uses an ArrayList that returns only the words that are different after making the words all lowercase in the file and uses the Scanner for this. I must sort the array in the end. I have to create two separate classes for this problem.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

 public class StackClass
 {
    static StringSet stringStack;
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


    stringStack = new StringSet();

    System.out.println("Please input the filename: ");
    String fileName = console.next();

    try {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext())
        {   
            input.useDelimiter("\\W");
            //lcString.toLowerCase();
              (I commented this out^ until I figure it out)
            stringStack.add(input.next());

        }
        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
 }
```

**And here is my other class:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringSet implements Iterable<String>
{
static Stack<String> stringStack;
private ArrayList<String> stackList = new ArrayList<String>();


//for loop goes through all the words in stack 
//if the word is found then ignore it, if not add it to the stack
public String add(String s)
{
    for(int i=0;i>0;i++)
    {
    stringStack.push(s);
    }
    return s;
}


public int size( int i)
{
    return stringStack.size();
}

public Iterator<String> iterator()
{return new WordIterator();}

class WordIterator implements Iterator<String>
{
    private int i=0;
    public boolean hasNext(){return i>0;}
    public String next(){return stackList<String>;}
}
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag as such.  Are you allowed to use a Set along the way to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: Why not put them into a set and return the set's iterator? The set will not allow duplicates

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: I changed it to homework...sorry!

Comment: Jeff, are you talking about a HashSet? I am not very familiar with those if so.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is "how to iterate only through unique words", I would simply use a HashSet for the words, and as you push words onto the stack

1) If the word is in the HashSet, don't push it on.
2) If the word is not in the HashSet, push it on and add it to the HashSet.

If you need to keep track of the number of occurrences, you can use a HashMap instead of a HashSet, where you increase the number of duplicate strings you encounter.

If you need to preserve the ordering & number of occurrences for something, I would keep a separate non-unique Stack where I'd just push everything.

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: To preserve the insertion order, you can use `LinkedHashSet` and `LinkedHashMap` instead of the regular ones.

Comment: thanks. We haven't really discussed HashSets yet. I have an idea of what to do but just don't know how to carry it out. I want to just read all the words into the array list and then sort the list. Then, I want to iterate through the list and compare each element to the one before and remove the element if it matches the previous one. I don't know when the best point would be to convert to lowercase letters though.